# How do i change my ios app update availability

Tags: iphone, ios, ipad

When I created my app update, I chose for it to become available right after it has been reviewed by apple, but I want to change this and choose another date for the update to be available for download. However, I can't find any option in itunes connect that allows me to do this. What should I do to change it?

Thanks for your help

Comment: I don't think you can; reject it and submit it again. These days I usually choose the "let me release it" option unless it's just a bugfix (with no PR planned) or a major crash fix.

Comment: Thanks for your answer! Next time i update my app i'll make sure to check the let me release it option.

Answer (score 0):

Under Pricing And Availability, You can select your date.

Comment: yeah but my application is already out it is only an update that i want to be available at a certain date while still keepinbg the original appplication available for download

Comment: Because right now the application update is in the process of being reviewed by apple but i dont want it to become available right after it has been reviewed